# how do I fix unregistered celery tasks when tasks are already registered?

Tags: python, redis, celery

I am trying to execute the following structure in order to have a more manageable folder - structure in order to have a dedicated folder for celery tasks for those who don't depend on Django project, but I am getting unregistered tasks when I have registered tasks from `app.autodiscover_tasks` what am I missing in my codebase? https://github.com/SkyBulk/celery/blob/main/thirdparty/celery_tasks/celery.py#L5

Let us focus on this path tree:

```
└── thirdparty
    ├── appone
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── tasks.py
    ├── apptwo
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── tasks.py
    └── celery_tasks
        ├── celery.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── settings.py
```

Relative to the outer project (as the sources root), the list of modules are:

```
thirdparty.appone.tasks (contains add)
thirdparty.apptwo.tasks (contains mult)
thirdparty.celery_tasks.celery (contains app)
thirdparty.celery_tasks.settings (contains CELERY_BROKER_URL, CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, etc.)
```

thirdparty/celery_tasks/**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from outside import file
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

thirdparty/celery_tasks/appone/tasks.py

```
import time
from celery import shared_task
from outside import file

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    print('start appone add function')
    time.sleep(10)
    file.fun()
    return x + y
```

thirdparty/celery_tasks/apptwo/tasks.py

```
import time
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def mult(x, y):
    print('start apptwo mult function')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('result:', x * y)
    return x * y
```

Error:

```
celery_1       | Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
celery_1       | Or maybe you're using relative imports?
celery_1       | 
celery_1       | Please see
celery_1       | http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
celery_1       | for more information.
celery_1       | 
celery_1       | The full contents of the message body was:
celery_1       | b'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
celery_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 562, in on_task_received
celery_1       |     strategy = strategies[type_]
celery_1       | KeyError: 'appone.tasks.add'
celery_1       | [2021-04-30 06:07:00,004: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'apptwo.tasks.mult'.
celery_1       | The message has been ignored and discarded.
```

Answer (score 0):

They might have been registered under a different name. I suggest you run `celery -A your.project inspect registered` (replace `your.project` with correct name) and check the registered tasks with what you expect to have registered.

Comment: ````
/usr/src/app # celery -A celery_tasks inspect registered
-> celery@292130da6337: OK
    * celery_tasks.appone.tasks.add
    * celery_tasks.apptwo.tasks.mult
```

Comment: So the actual task name is `celery_tasks.appone.tasks.add`, not `appone.tasks.add`. I guess that is why you are getting the KeyError.